# mongodb aggregate 2 tables with at least 1 entry on a linked table [nodejs]

Tags: mongodb

I have two tables and I'd like to extract all tags where there is at least 1 share object with that tag. I also need it created within last 7 days.

I'm terrible at aggregate. Anyone can help?

"retrieve tags (table 1) when there is at least a share (table 2) createdAt within last 7 days"

In the below example, only tagId 3 and 4 should be retrieved. Am using nodejs

Shares:

- _id: 1, tagId: 3, createdAt: 21-Jul
- _id: 2, tagId: 4, createdAt: 21-Jul
- _id: 3, tagId: 4, createdAt: 21-Jul

Tag:

- _id: 3
- _id: 4
- _id: 5

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate `$lookup` operator and then `$match` to filter out the one which was not created in last 7 days

```
db.tags.aggregate([
  { $lookup: 
    { 
      from: "shares", 
      localField: "_id", 
      foreignField: "tagId", 
      as: "shares" 
    } 
  }, 
  { $project:
    {
      name:1,
      createdAt:"$shares.createdAt"
    }
  }, 
  {$unwind:"$createdAt"}, 
  { $match: 
    { $expr: 
      { $gte: [
                {"$dateFromString": {"dateString": "$createdAt"}},
                { $subtract:["$$NOW", 7*24*60*60*1000]}
              ] 
        
      } 
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Sorry, it dosen't seem to work the $project just seems to return the tag info?

Answer (score 0):

This aggregate query `$lookup` operator and then `pipeline` inside `$lookup` to filter out the records which was created in last 7 days.

```
db.tags.aggregate([
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'share', 
      'let': {
        'tag_id': '$_id'
      }, 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$match': {
            '$expr': {
              '$and': [
                {
                  '$eq': [
                    '$tagId', '$$tag_id'
                  ]
                }, {
                  '$gte': [
                    {
                      '$dateFromString': {
                        'dateString': '$createdAt'
                      }
                    }, {
                      '$subtract': [
                        '$$NOW', 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ], 
      'as': 'shares'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'shares.0': {
        '$exists': true
      }
    }
  }
])
```